# <Audio> fallback through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, embed, html5-audio

I want to understand how to implement HTML5 `<audio>` fallback using Javascript...

i.e. I have a div on my page, to which , I dynamically append `<embed>` tag when "Play audio" link is clicked currently..
i.e. I currently use

```
function playSound(audioUrl)
{
var x = document.getElementById("playAudio");
x.innerHTML = '<EMBED src="'+audioUrl+'" autostart=true loop=false volume=100 hidden=true>';
}
```

I want to have the same thing implemented using the HTML5 `<audio>` tag, But want to fallback to embed when HTML5 audio tag is not supported. How can I implement the same using JS given that the Audio URL is kind of dynamic ?

My intention is it should work on older as well as newer browsers..like IE6,7,8; FF 3,4; Chrome; Safari 4,5 on MAC, Safari on iPad..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect `audio` support.

If you don't want to include that library for a simple thing, this should do it...

```
var audioSupport = document.createElement('audio').hasOwnProperty('src');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Y7LrD/).

So that would be...

```
function playSound(audioUrl) {
    var audioSupport = document.createElement('audio').hasOwnProperty('src'),
        x = document.getElementById("playAudio");

    if (audioSupport) {
        var audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.src = audioUrl;
        x.appendChild(audio);
        audio.play();
    } else {
        // Or you could use proper DOM methods...
        x.innerHTML = '<EMBED src="' + audioUrl + '" autostart=true loop=false volume=100 hidden=true>';
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/8WNJY/).

Comment: Cool..Thx a lot..So just to confirm there would be no need required within the HTML code..i.e. I have a blank div in the HTML <div id="playAudio"></div> ...So that would remain as it is and everything will be controlled from JS itself..

Comment: Hey..and one more thing...Is it necessary to change the DOCTYPE of the page to DOCTYPE html i.e. to specify HTML5 ?

Comment: I tried the above code and for some reason, it is not working on iPad Safari (says "movie cannot be played", even though it is actually a mp3)...THOUGH works perfect on Desktop Safari..it appends the HTML5 audio in desktop Safari..