# Audio files and WWW

Tags: html, html5-audio

I need to find good way of embedding audio files on a website.
I find out about the based  tag in HTML5. But there is an issue of playing music in other format than .mp3 in Firefox and Opera.
The player should be also similar in each browser.
Can you recommend me anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-audio-element) [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Audio) is ***the*** way to do what you want.

There are [shims for browsers that don't already support `<audio>`](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills), and you can [offer fallback formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Fallback_options) using the [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Source) tag, for maximum cross-browser compatibility.

More reading, if you're still unsure:

- [<Audio> fallback through Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251638/audio-fallback-through-javascript)
- [Native audio in the browser](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/)
- [Quick Guide to Implementing the HTML5 Audio Tag (with Fallback to Flash)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/)